# How to find where Class1 is referenced in Class2 using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, static-analysis

I am trying to run some primitive static code analysis and, for starters, I want to find all the references to Class1 in Class2, similar to how an IDE find usage for a class (e.g. methods and line numbers). Just browsing throw the [reflection javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), I was not able to detect a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* however do it with a technology that understands byte code analysis. [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) is an example of such a technology.

You'd create a [`ClassVisitor`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html) with a [`MethodVisitor`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html) that does its magic in [`visitMethodInsn(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitMethodInsn%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

But I'd say it's way easier to use an IDE and do a Usage search (both Eclipse and IntelliJ do that very well)

Comment: do the IDEs use that API ?

Comment: also, do you know of any alternatives to this approach?

Comment: Ides work with source code, they generate such lookups based on the abstract syntax tree. The approach is pretty similar, you'll write visitors for method invocations, either on source or byte code

Answer (score 2):

Java reflection cannot inspect the internal implementation of methods and classes; only the external API.  This cannot be done with reflection.